Allocating more space to my locked root partition
I've tried to find my particular issue elsewhere but can't seem to. I have a dual booted Window's/Linux PC, and I can't install the new update for Ubuntu because I don't have enough space in the root partition. I'm trying to add space there, but it is locked and saying it's at it's maximum. I have 77 unallocated GB but can't seem to use them. Upon my research I've noticed a couple things that people need/ask for so I'm including them here.


As I was writing this comment I tried to do things on the links that were populated. Didn't get anywhere. If you want me to go back and do something else then I can, but I would really appreciate your feedback on where I went wrong and why it didn't work. I'm not saying that I give up. I just may be doing it wrong or not understanding the concept enough to execute properly.
--edit
Tried following the first answer and came across this:


From a live Ubuntu session.
Loading is complete.
Open a terminal
Run in it
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall gparted
sudo gparted

From Gparted
Create an ext4 partition in the unallocated space of 70.77 gigas
Apply the changes.
Unmount if /dev/sda6 was mounted
Right click and choose copy
Once copy is complete.
Position yourself in the new 70.77 gig partition and choose paste.
Apply the changes.
Try rebooting from the hard drive
If everything is correct, delete the /dev/sda6 partition and recreate it in ext4 system to be able to use it as you see fit.
If any inconvenience occurs, start Gparted in a live session and delete the 70.77 gig partition, so that everything remains as it was at the beginning

it was all working until I tried unmounting. Then I got a new error message. Will link in original question because it isn't allowing me to add here.

A process is using that drive and to prevent data loss the kernel will not allow you to unmount it. Are you in a Live Ubuntu session? If you are in a live session, find the PID of the process causing the problems. sudo lsof /dev/sda6. Once you get the PID, sudo kill -9 PID
